# Generating Scala code trees from a Scala compiler plugin

Tags: scala, plugins, compiler-construction, code-generation

There are a [few](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/140) [resources](http://scaladudes.com/node/26) on the web that are instructive in writing Scala compiler plugins that pattern-match against the code, but these don't help in generating code (constructing symbol trees). Where should I start to figure out how to do this? (If there's an easier way than to manually build symbol trees, I'd be interested as well.)

For instance, I'd like write a plugin that replaces some code with a simple AST for this expression, where the variables (extracted from the original program code) could be of any type:

```
"" + hello + ", " + world + "!"
```

I realize this may be tricky because of boxing and `toString`, e.g. if
`hello` were an object and `world` were an int, this should really be
something like:

```
"".+(hello.toString().+(", ".+(new Integer(world).toString().+("!"))))
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but Miguel Garcia has put together the [Scala Compiler Corner](http://www.sts.tu-harburg.de/people/mi.garcia/ScalaCompilerCorner/) which is probably the best available compilation of resources about the Scala compiler.

Answer (score 3):

If you generate the tree before the `erasure` compiler phase, you can type `hello` and `world` with `Any`, and call `toString` on them.

```
 ~: cat test.scala 
object test {
  def f(hello: Any, world: Any) = "" + hello + ", " + world + "!"
  f("1", "2")
  f(1, 1)
}
 ~: scalac -Xprint:typer test.scala 
[[syntax trees at end of typer]]// Scala source: test.scala
package <empty> {
  final object test extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object test = {
      test.super.this();
      ()
    };
    def f(hello: Any, world: Any): java.lang.String = "".+(hello).+(", ").+(world).+("!");
    test.this.f("1", "2");
    test.this.f(1, 1)
  }
}

~: scalac -Xprint:erasure test.scala 
[[syntax trees at end of erasure]]// Scala source: test.scala
package <empty> {
  final class test extends java.lang.Object with ScalaObject {
    def this(): object test = {
      test.super.this();
      ()
    };
    def f(hello: java.lang.Object, world: java.lang.Object): java.lang.String = "".+(hello).+(", ").+(world).+("!");
    test.this.f("1", "2");
    test.this.f(scala.Int.box(1), scala.Int.box(1))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't really tell me how to generate an AST.

Answer (score 2):

you might find something in this project:
http://github.com/scala-incubator/autoproxy-plugin

Comment: Unfortunately, this plugin wasn't really instructive in how to construct ASTs.

Answer (score 1):

This thread looks relevant:
[Convert Scala AST to source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432554/scala-convert-ast-to-source-code)

Specifically, you can construct Scala AST with the `TreeDSL` mentioned.
http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/TreeDSL.html

Comment: Update: There's a project that expands on the TreeDSL and looks quite usable: https://github.com/eed3si9n/treehugger