# Convert Scala AST to source code

Tags: scala, abstract-syntax-tree

Given a Scala AST, is there a way to generate Scala source code?

I'm looking into ways to autogenerate Scala source by parsing/analyzing other Scala source. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been successfully using [Scala-Refactoring](http://scala-refactoring.org/) by Mirko Stocker for this task.

For synthetically constructing ASTs, it relies strongly on the existing [Tree DSL](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/ast/TreeDSL.html) of Scala's NSC.

Although the code is a bit messy, you can find an example usage in my project [ScalaCollider-UGens](https://github.com/Sciss/ScalaColliderUGens).

I have also come across a very useful class by [Johannes Rudolph](https://github.com/jrudolph/scala-enhanced-strings/blob/new-transform/src/main/scala/net/virtualvoid/string/MyNodePrinter.scala).

Answer (score 0):

See our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).

DMS provides a complete ecosystem for parsing/analyzing/optimizing/transforming source code in many languages.  It achieves this by provide generic machinery for these tasks as its core capabilities, and specializing those according to explicitly supplied language definitions ("front ends").  DMS has front ends for many languages (C, C++, C#, Java, COBOL, ...) that have been used in anger, and a process for defining others very quickly.

We work on expanding the language set more or less continuously.  DMS already has parts of a Scala front end implemented, and we know how to finish it based on the other 30+ front ends we have built, with special emphasis on knowledge of Java.

Comment: "have been used in anger"?  Was that a typo?

Comment: @Malvolio: that is an English idiom meaning "used for real purposes"